# Godaddy URL Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS won't work Plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

First I have looked at resolutions all around on stackoverflow as well as googling the heck out of this and even going to godaddy support(lack there of support)

I am on godaddy using windows (plesk). my site is written in C# mvc. I setup my SSL cert and I am able to access the site through https. when I try to access through http it does not redirect but instead gives me a 403.4 error. 
I tried the URL rewrite like suggested on Godaddy's help section 
https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828

I have even copied a URL rewrite we use at work on one of our production sites on our own servers.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Remove www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

none of that seems to work, godaddy is blaming it on the Cert not being propagated, but if that were the case than HTTPS should not work and I shouldn't be getting a 403.4 error but instead some other related error at best.

Require SSL is enabled on the godaddy server

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by unchecking "Require SSL" and now it redirects.